# На странице выборов появляются кнопки на английском языке: Save changes & Cancel

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы

При нажатии кнопки <kbd>Редактировать</kbd> [на странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) появляются кнопки на английском языке:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Эта развлекуха будет вечной. Пока на той стороне не сделают нормальную локализацию (из нейтрального языка, а не из английского), не стоит и стараться.

Comment: Не только там. На странице тура тоже кнопки не локализованы. И их нет в трансифексе. Я вроде про это ещё в том году на MSE писал)

Answer (score 1):

Добавил перевод для "Save changes":

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10881

Для "Cancel" [уже был давно](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/9066), но может здесь просто не было локализовано.

Стоит проверить на ближайших сборках. Текущая rev 2020.9.4.37557